# How should I create for nestjs response dto?

Tags: nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

How should I create the dto for the nestjs response?
I am currently creating the following code.
I want to define it like the dto of input parameters.

■ response code like this

```
return {
    statusCode: 200,
    message: 'successs',
    data: {
        id: 10
    }
}
```

■ I want to do like this

```
async test: Promise<SuccessDto> {
    return respoinse: SuccessDto
}
```

Comment: TransformationInterceptor can I use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is no need to do that. You can access the code through the headers and the convention is the following

- 200 is ok / success,
- 201 is created,
- 204 is no response,
- 400 is bad request,
- 401 is unauthorized,
- 403 is forbidden,
- 404 is not found

But to answer your question, it might be possible through interceptors. Their sandbox :

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/21-serializer/src/app.controller.ts

use the [Res](https://docs.nestjs.com/controllers#request-object), create a DTO with a generic or a class to extends it and glue it together. Use the [@Type(() => YourDTO)](https://dev.to/avantar/validating-nested-objects-with-class-validator-in-nestjs-1gn8) to expose what you need. But your kind of reinventing the wheel, NestJS takes care of it and you can overwrite the Response status if needed.

Comment: thanks. I created TransformationInterceptor and use. I think it's berry nice. but message is not need? it's generally response format?

Comment: https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/operations is it useful ?

Comment: Operations are only for Swagger. It does not affect your code per se. Yes the message you are proposing to use is not necessary, it's duplicating the http status you send back.